# Microsoft Azure Master-Slave worker roles

Tags: azure

I am trying to port an application to azure platform. I want to run an existing application multiple times. My initial idea is as follows: I have a master_process. I have many slave_processes. Each process is a worker role in Azure. Each slave_process will run an instance of the application independently. I want master_process to start many slave_processes and provide them the input arguments. At the end, master_process will collect the results. Currently, I have a working setup for calling the whole application from a C# wrapper. So, for the success, I need two things: First, I have to find a way to start slave workers inside of a master worker (just like threads). Second, I need to find a way to store results of the slave workers and reach these result files from master worker. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try and solve the problem differently.  Deploying a whole new instance can take 15 to 30 minutes.  Adding extra instances to an already running worker role is a little quicker, but not by much.  I'm going to presume that you want results faster than that and that this process is something that is run frequently.

I would have just one worker role type that runs your existing logic and as many instances of that worker role that you determine you'll need.  Whatever your client is will decide that it needs to break the work up in a certain number of pieces, let's say 10 for the sake of argument.  It will give each piece of work an ID (e.g. a guid) and then put 10 messages that contain the parameters and the ID into a queue.  Your worker role instances take messages out of the queue, do their work and write their results to storage somewhere (either SQL Azure, Azure Table Storage or maybe even blob storage depending on what the results are).  The client polls that storage to wait for all of the results to be complete and then carries on.

If this is a process that is only run infrequently, then rather than having the worker roles deployed all of the time, you could use the same method I've described, but in addition get the client code to [deploy the worker roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460813.aspx) when it starts and then [delete them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460815.aspx) when it's finished through the management API.  There are [samples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows-azure-code-samples.aspx) on how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation you might find useful:

I have a large sequential batch process I run in Azure which requires pre and post processing.  The technique I used was to use instances of a single multifunctional worker role, but to use a "quorum" to nominate a head node, which then controls the workflow.

They way I do it is using an azure **page** blob as the quorum (basically a kind of global mutex/lock), because once a node grabs it for writing it's locked. For resilience, in case there's an issue with the head node, all nodes occasionally try to recapture the quorum.